# Executable that is was code signed on Windows 10 not recognized in Windows 7

Tags: exe, code-signing, pfx

Using a .pfx file, I code signed an executable on Windows 10 using the signtool program. When I went to install on windows 10, the OS was able to recognized that the executable came from our company. When I transfer the executable to another Windows 10 computer, it too is able to recognize that the file came from our company.

However, when I transfer the executable to Windows 7, the OS states that the executable is from an unknown publisher.

I am wondering what the cause for this could be and if there is a method to have windows 7 recognize the publisher.

Note, that the pfx file was not generated by hand, we went to a third party for the pfx file generation.

Edit:

Here is the signtool command that I used.

```
signtool sign /f myCert.pfx /p password test.exe
```

Note that the password is not actually password.

The certificate was issued by Comodo.

Comment: Is the Windows 7 machine fully up-to-date?

Comment: Please post the options you used with signtool.exe, and tell us what Certificate Authority issued your signing certificate.

Comment: Updated to include the options for sign tool. Also the windows 7 machines do have SP1 on them. That is all that I can tell.

Comment: Also added in who issued the certificate